# Can't Start odoo 16 from source ! I Got ERROR odoo16 odoo.tools.convert.init: Could not eval(False) for active in {}

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, odoo, virtualenv

I need some help please, I was trying to run **odoo 16 from source using a linux Mint machine**.
**unfortunately**, when i start debugging, I got those errors :

```
2023-10-28 20:27:49,018 191168 ERROR odoo16 odoo.tools.convert.init: Could not eval(False) for active in {} 
2023-10-28 20:27:49,042 191168 ERROR odoo16 odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='installed' WHERE state IN ('to remove', 'to upgrade')
ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='installed' WHERE state IN...
```

Note : **The database was created but with no tables**!!!!

I made those steps :

1. I installed python 12.
2. I installed PostgreSql database + PgAdmin4 (**all working fine**)
3. I made a new user :odoo16 with superuser permission.
4. I downloaded odoo-16.0 from [github](https://github.com/odoo/odoo)
5. I downloaded all dependency from requirement.txt into a virtual environment .
   **My working folder structure :**
   [image]
   **My configuration file :**

```
[options]
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo16
db_password = odoo16
addons_path = /media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/addons
default_productivity_apps = True
http_port = 8069
server_wide_modules = web
```

**My VSCode configuration :
launch.json **

```
{    
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "odoo16-start",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/odoo-16.0/odoo-bin",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                
                "--config=${workspaceRoot}/conf/odoo16.conf",
                "--database=odoo16",
                "-i",
                "base"
                           
                // Use this to exit the external terminal
                //"&&", "exit",
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Odoo16-Upgrade",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/odoo-16.0/odoo-bin",
            "args": [
                "-c", "${workspaceRoot}/conf/odoo16.conf",
                "-u", "my_module_01",
                "-d", "oc12_local_02",
                // Use this to exit the external terminal
                //"&&", "exit"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        },
    ]
}
```

**And setting.json :**

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath":"/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/virtual-env/bin/python3.12",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--init-hook",
        "import sys; sys.path.extend([\"\"/home/smichi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.devicesimulatorexpress-2020.0.36321/out\"\",\"\"/home/smichi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.devicesimulatorexpress-2020.0.36321/out/micropython\"\",\"\"/home/smichi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.devicesimulatorexpress-2020.0.36321/out/clue\"\",\"\"/home/smichi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.devicesimulatorexpress-2020.0.36321/out/base_circuitpython\"\"])"
    ]
}
```

The whole output :

```
(virtual-env) smichi@smichi-HP:/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0$  cd /media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0 ; /usr/bin/env /media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/virtual-env/bin/python3.12 /home/smichi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.20.2/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 60825 -- /media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo-bin --config=/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/conf/odoo16.conf --database=odoo16 -i base 
2023-10-28 20:27:31,182 191168 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 16.0 
2023-10-28 20:27:31,183 191168 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/conf/odoo16.conf 
2023-10-28 20:27:31,183 191168 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/addons', '/home/smichi/.local/share/Odoo/addons/16.0', '/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/addons'] 
2023-10-28 20:27:31,184 191168 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo16@localhost:5432 
2023-10-28 20:27:32,230 191168 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
2023-10-28 20:27:32,675 191168 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on smichi-HP:8069 
2023-10-28 20:27:32,687 191168 INFO ? odoo.modules.loading: init db 
2023-10-28 20:27:34,973 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules... 
2023-10-28 20:27:34,974 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.modules.loading: Loading module base (1/1) 
2023-10-28 20:27:35,070 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.modules.registry: module base: creating or updating database tables 
2023-10-28 20:27:39,080 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of ir.module.module.menus_by_module 
2023-10-28 20:27:39,081 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of ir.module.module.reports_by_module 
2023-10-28 20:27:39,081 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of ir.module.module.views_by_module 
2023-10-28 20:27:40,830 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.partner.user_id 
2023-10-28 20:27:40,830 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.partner.commercial_partner_id 
2023-10-28 20:27:40,831 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.partner.display_name 
2023-10-28 20:27:40,831 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.partner.company_registry 
2023-10-28 20:27:40,832 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.partner.commercial_company_name 
2023-10-28 20:27:40,832 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.partner.partner_share 
2023-10-28 20:27:41,344 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.currency.decimal_places 
2023-10-28 20:27:41,629 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.company.logo_web 
2023-10-28 20:27:42,007 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.users.signature 
2023-10-28 20:27:42,009 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.models: Prepare computation of res.users.share 
2023-10-28 20:27:49,015 191168 INFO odoo16 odoo.modules.loading: loading base/data/res_bank.xml 
2023-10-28 20:27:49,018 191168 ERROR odoo16 odoo.tools.convert.init: Could not eval(False) for active in {} 
2023-10-28 20:27:49,042 191168 ERROR odoo16 odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='installed' WHERE state IN ('to remove', 'to upgrade')
ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='installed' WHERE state IN...
               ^
 
2023-10-28 20:27:49,043 191168 ERROR odoo16 odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 698, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 573, in _tag_record
    f_val = _eval_xml(self, field, env)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 117, in _eval_xml
    return safe_eval(a_eval, idref2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 39, in <lambda>
    safe_eval = lambda expr, ctx={}: s_eval(expr, ctx, nocopy=True)
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 360, in safe_eval
    c = test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode, filename=filename)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 218, in test_expr
    assert_valid_codeobj(allowed_codes, code_obj, expr)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 191, in assert_valid_codeobj
    raise ValueError("forbidden opcode(s) in %r: %s" % (expr, ', '.join(opname[x] for x in (code_codes - allowed_codes))))
ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in 'False': RETURN_CONST

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 90, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 429, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, processed_modules = load_module_graph(
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 231, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 71, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 763, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 829, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 749, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 698, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 711, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/addons/base/data/res_bank.xml:5, somewhere inside
<record id="res_bank_1" model="res.bank">
            <field name="name">Reserve</field>
            <field name="active" eval="False"/>
        </record>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 92, in new
    odoo.modules.reset_modules_state(db_name)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 635, in reset_modules_state
    cr.execute(
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/sql_db.py", line 321, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='installed' WHERE state IN...
               ^

2023-10-28 20:27:49,052 191168 CRITICAL odoo16 odoo.service.server: Failed to initialize database `odoo16`. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 698, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 573, in _tag_record
    f_val = _eval_xml(self, field, env)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 117, in _eval_xml
    return safe_eval(a_eval, idref2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 39, in <lambda>
    safe_eval = lambda expr, ctx={}: s_eval(expr, ctx, nocopy=True)
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 360, in safe_eval
    c = test_expr(expr, _SAFE_OPCODES, mode=mode, filename=filename)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 218, in test_expr
    assert_valid_codeobj(allowed_codes, code_obj, expr)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 191, in assert_valid_codeobj
    raise ValueError("forbidden opcode(s) in %r: %s" % (expr, ', '.join(opname[x] for x in (code_codes - allowed_codes))))
ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in 'False': RETURN_CONST

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 90, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 429, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, processed_modules = load_module_graph(
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 231, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 71, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 763, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 829, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 749, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 698, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 711, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/addons/base/data/res_bank.xml:5, somewhere inside
<record id="res_bank_1" model="res.bank">
            <field name="name">Reserve</field>
            <field name="active" eval="False"/>
        </record>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/service/server.py", line 1299, in preload_registries
    registry = Registry.new(dbname, update_module=update_module)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<decorator-gen-16>", line 2, in new
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 92, in new
    odoo.modules.reset_modules_state(db_name)
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 635, in reset_modules_state
    cr.execute(
  File "/media/smichi/Data2/Odoo16.0/odoo-16.0/odoo/sql_db.py", line 321, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE ir_module_module SET state='installed' WHERE state IN...
```

**I appreciate any help , THANKS **

Answer (score 1):

Odoo will raise the [forbidden opcode](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py#L166-L167) error when it tries to evaluate `False` expression because of the newly added opcode in `Python 12` : [RETURN_CONST](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#cpython-bytecode-changes)

To fix this issue downgrade the Python version

Comment: Oh THANKS , you saved my life. As you said, I downgraded my python version to 3.8, and all errors are gone, and odoo server started correctly, data base was created with all tables (123 tables).THANKS AGAIN :)